# How to Calculate RGB Hex Color Variations with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, hex

I'm trying to programmatically create some css borders and text-shadows (for a letterpress effect) with jQuery.

Given an RGB color value, I'd like to be able to calculate color variations [much like 0to255 does](http://0to255.com/).

For example, [given the color #023f74](http://0to255.com/023f74), how do I come up with 4 shades lighter being #0363b7?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could convert the RGB color ro HSL or HSB / HSV then apply the variation and then back to RGB!

look here -> http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH <- for formulas for converting from and to HSL / HSB/ HSV and others...

Answer (score 1):

A little play with hex - from any given color increment\decrement with a certain step until the end of the scale, white(fff shortened from ffffff) or black (000 - form 000000).